# Activar validaciones de HTML5 desde Js

Tags: jquery, formularios, form-submit, submit

tengo este js, y este html:

```
$(document).on('click', '.validar', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var cantidad = 0;

        var obj = {
            "correo": $(".txtEmail").attr("id")
        };
        $.each(obj, function (identificador, value) {
            cantidad = ($.onlyData("#" + value));
            if (cantidad > 0) {
                toastr["error"]("Este " + identificador + " ya se encuentra registrado!");
            } else {
                $("#msform").submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNewClient" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nuevo cliente</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Client', array('class' => '', 'id' => 'msform'));
            ?>
            <div class="input-group">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('contact', array('label' => array('text' => " "),
                    'placeholder' => 'Danos tu nombre', 
                    "required" => "true", 
                    "minlength" => "5", 
                    "maxlength" => "", 
                    'class' => 'form-control-custom color-input validLength txtContact lang prettyName', 
                    'key' => 'txtContact'));
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('company', array('label' => array('text' => " "),
                    'placeholder' => '¿Para que marca vamos a trabajar?', "required" => "true", 
                    "minlength" => "3", 
                    "maxlength" => "",
                    'data-sql' => "company-Client",
                    'class' => 'form-control-custom color-input validLength txtClient lang prettyName', 
                    'key' => 'txtClient'));
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => array('text' => " "),
                    'placeholder' => 'Correo electronico', 
                    "data-DB" => "email", 
                    "required" => "true", 
                    "minlength" => "5", 
                    'data-sql' => "username-User",
                    "maxlength" => "", 
                    'class' => 'form-control-custom color-input validLength prettyName txtEmail lang validEmail', 
                    'key' => 'txtEmail'));
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('label' => array('text' => " "),
                    'placeholder' => 'Celular', "minlength" => "7", "required" => "true", "maxlength" => "10", 'class' => 'form-control-custom color-input validLength txtPhone blockLetter lang', 'key' => 'txtPhone'));
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Guardar cliente', 'class' => 'validar')) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

la cosa es que ese js, valida si un campo ya xiste en la BD, pero no se si hay alguna forma de activar, las validaciones automaticas de html5 desde el js, en internet encontre esta :`$("#elemento").checkValidity();`
pero no funciono, estaba pensando en algo `$("#formId").checkRequired();` o algo por el estilo, pero no he podido encontrar nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esas son las validaciones de html5 y lo que quiero es activarlas desde jquery es decir con alguna funcion decirle que haga las validaciones que normalmente hacel el html5 al darle a un submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pregunta sigue siendo muy amplia, necesitas darnos mas información como por ejemplo en que momento quieres que se haga el revisado o como quieres que se ejecute... con un botón sin submit, al teclear, al salir del campo, etc...

Como nota `checkValidity()` es un método de JavaScript, no de jQuery. Por lo que si quieres usarlo en un objeto de jQuery deberías usar `$("#MiForma")[0].checkValidity()`

Pero ya que en tu pregunta solo pides una función que valide los campos puedes intentar esto:

```
function validar (){
    var forma = document.getElementById("MiForma");
  if(forma.checkValidity()){
    console.log("Forma Válida");
    $("#MiForma").submit();
  }else{
  $("#enviar").click()
    console.log("Forma invalida, deberían salir mensajes html5");
}}
```

Comment: Al parecer esa funciono, pero explicame por que [0]?

Comment: Me alegra que preguntes el por qué [0]. Los objetos de jQuery no solo guardan un solo objeto del DOM, pueden guardar múltiples como si fuera un arreglo. " $() " es solo un selector que puede traer N objetos del DOM que correspondan a esa selección.

Comment: Si entendí es como una consulta sql, el [0]quiere decir el primer  $("#MiForma"), si fuera [1] seria el segundo form con ese id, verdad?

Comment: Exactamente. Siempre que quieras referirte a un objeto del DOM en particular de un selector de jQuery debes usar su número de index.

Answer (score 0):

depende amigo de la validacion que desees realizar, por ejemplo si deseas que un input sea required, entonces puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("txtinput1").attributes["required"] = "";
```

esto en javascript, asi que creo que deberia ser mas especifico en el asunto, pero de esta manera puedes hacerlo.
Puedes hacer una validación como indicas en la actualización, pero no te quedaria igual que la validacion de html5 con la burbuja flotante, si no que te quedaria un recuadro rojo en el campo o verde, y un mensaje debajo, te añado documentacion acerca de esto:
del lado html lo siguiente (en el form llamas una funcion javascript con el evento `onsubmit` o llamas la funcion en el evento `onkeyup`):

```
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  Campo ingresar:<br>
  <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="direccion@correo.com" onkeyup="myFunction()">
  <div id="salida" style="color: red;"></div>
  <br>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

en javascript lo siguiente:

```
function mifunction(){
event.preventDefault();
        var cantidad = 0;
        var verificado= true;

        var obj = {
            "correo": $(".txtEmail").attr("id")
        };
        $.each(obj, function (identificador, value) {
            cantidad = ($.onlyData("#" + value));
            if (cantidad > 0) {
                document.getElementById("correo").style.borderColor = "#b03535";//esto pone color rojo el campo
                document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML = ("Ya se encuentra registrado"); //esto muestra un mensaje en el div salida
                verificador=false; //esto evita que el formulario se envie
            } 
        });
if (verificador==false){
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta agregándole lo que quiero sacar

Comment: @AndrésVélez ya aplique cambios a mi respuesta de acuerdo a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Segun tengo entendido el return false no funciona porque esta en un ciclo así que solo lo sacaria del each, tendría que hacerse con una bandera

Comment: Si tienes razon, lo siento, puedes utilizar una variable fuera del each y en la funcion un if que pregunte acerca de dicha variable...

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi respuesta  @AndrésVélez

Comment: Listo gracias, oye pero pienso que no es necesario el if, o eso creo ya que podrías decir `return verificador` y al este ser `false` se sale del js